# View win32 debug output in Azure App Services

Tags: azure, winapi, azure-web-app-service, isapi

We have an isapi service running in Azure App Services.

It uses OutputDebugString to output debug messages.

Is it possible to view this stream anywhere in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use [DebugView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/debugview) to capture Win32 debug output

Comment: Hi, @Jonny, Does this answer your question? Please feel free to contact me if you have any issue and if this really helps you, please also feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer.

Comment: Hi @Drake-Wu-MSFT - Apologies for the long wait for a response! We use debugview when we have access to a desktop and it works really well. Is it possible to target it at an Azure App Service?

Comment: You need to start DebugView as administrator, and use the Capture | Capture Global Win32 menu item to see log messages from ISAPI apps